# How to use Github Actions with Azure Devops Pipelines

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-actions

I am trying to run an azure devops pipeline kicked off by github actions.

The started example from [Azure Pipelines](https://github.com/Azure/pipelines) is this:

```
- uses: Azure/pipelines@v1
  with:
    azure-devops-project-url: 'https://dev.azure.com/organization/project-name'
    azure-pipeline-name: 'pipeline-name' # name of the Azure pipeline to be triggered
    azure-devops-token: '${{ secrets.AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN }}'
```

I am structuring mine akin to this:

```
name: workflow 
on: push

jobs:
 deploy-using-azure-pipelines:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: 'Trigger an Azure Pipeline to deploy the app to PRODUCTION'
      uses: Azure/pipelines@v1
      with:
        azure-devops-project-url: 'https://dev.azure.com/AccountName/ProjectName'
        azure-pipeline-name: 'WebApp_Azure_Prod' 
        azure-devops-token: '${{ secrets.AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN }}'
```

I have the proper secrets defined, and this is in my git as `push.yml` under the workflows folder, and I have set the proper pipeline name and project url. How can I improve this so that it is functional?

Comment: Can you show us the error log? In the post above, the project-url does not have proper accountName and projectName

Answer (score 0):

1. Try and validate your code using [yaml validator](https://yamlvalidator.com/).
2. Make sure you've added your azure-devops-token onto your GitHub project settings for Secrets page.
3. Try and lower case the `Azure/pipelines@v1` to `azure/pipelines@v1`.

Otherwise, your code looks very similar to the same code I run and it's working for me.